# How to insure all data entered in multiple UITextFields is accepted

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have several (43) UITextFields that I create programmatically in a UIPopoverController; most of the time the user forgets to tap the return key for his/her last entry, thus causing the the data not to be *accepted* in the last  text field when the popover loses focus.  The last textfield to have data entered is not necessarily the 43rd, it could be any of the textfields.

This is the code where I create the textFields; am I missing something regarding *FirstResponder*?:

```
//  create the UITextFields ("Database Fields") for user to match against their input field positions
CGRect nbrFieldRect = CGRectMake(x-20, y, 30.0f, 26.0f);
UITextField *nbrTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:nbrFieldRect];
nbrTextField.backgroundColor = colorYES? UIColorFromRGB(0xFFF9AF):[UIColor whiteColor];
nbrTextField.enabled = YES;
[nbrTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
nbrTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
nbrTextField.tag = tagNumber;
nbrTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
nbrTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
nbrTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyContinue;
nbrTextField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
nbrTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[nbrTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(mapUserFields:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];  //  map contents when user has finished entering it
nbrTextField.delegate = self;

[theView addSubview:nbrTextField];
```

Is there a way to somehow catch this and automatically correct the situation?

Comment: Updated the question:  ... causing the data not be be *accepted* in the last field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it (with a kludge)... added another UITextField for the user to put his initials in; not going to use the input (initials) at this time, if ever, but it moved the focus away from the last *nbrTextField*.

Thank you for your suggestions, I appreciate your time.  SD

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the `UITextFieldDelegate`’s method
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;`
The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting) say:
*The text field calls this method when it is asked to resign the first responder status. This can happen when the user selects another control or when you call the text field’s resignFirstResponder method. Before the focus change occurs, however, the text field calls this method and gives you a chance to prevent the change from happening.*
So this should give you a chance to store the last text fields contents.

Comment: Why not? Is this delegate method not called?

Comment: No, never called... and to further complicate matters, I don't know which of the 40+ textFields is the last field either...

Comment: ... but you are sure that you have set the textField's delegate?

Comment: @interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,...

Comment: This is not enough. This only ensures that you have implemented the required delegate methods. But these are only called, if you set the `delegate`property of the textfield, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619595-delegate?language=objc)